# Is there a site that pairs up wanna be coaches with students

Tags: online-chess

People who either love teaching for free or that want to build some cliental who will give free lessons for a period of time or to practice there art of dispensing knowledge. Is there such a thing on the major sites that offer free chess or has anybody heard of talk of offering such a thing chess.com or lichess.com perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lichess has a [coaches page](https://lichess.org/coach) where titled players offer coaching in several languages.

Some of them offer discounts and a free first lesson.

---

If you are looking for something more casual, there are some chess [Discord](https://discord.com/) servers that might be of interest to you. [Chess Academy](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/community/chess-discord-server-chess-academy) has a channel called **#find-training-partners**, which is used by players who want to share knowledge and help each other. Another one is [ChessDojo](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/e9bkm4/new_discord_server_all_about_chess_improvement/), which also has a **#find-training-partners** as well as a **#coaching-discussion** channel.

Comment: Also, it seems that currently there is a running event for free coaching on https://www.reddit.com/r/chess where they have a post related to it every month. For example, the one for February 2022: https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/shmmqd/coach_a_player_february_2022/

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have suspected, both lichess.org and chess.com have resources where students can find coaches:

- hb20007 already pointed out that lichess' coaches page is at: https://lichess.org/coach
- The chess.com coaches page is at: https://www.chess.com/coaches

Some other suggestions for finding a coach:

- A web search can also find coaches. The lichess and chess.com pages above are the only results I saw on the first results page which provide a list. The remaining results are web sites of coaches, which is itself a list you can look through.
- US Chess has a list of coaches who have gone through its certification program at:
  http://www.uschess.org/index.php/Scholastic-Misc/Certified-Chess-Coach-List.html
- Results will vary, but your local/regional/national organization may list coaches in your area.

Note I couldn't find a list for FIDE certified trainers, although they have a program for that. Perhaps someone with better search skills or more patience will have more luck.

At least some coaches will offer free lessons as a sample. Some may offer lessons or group classes on a "Pay what you can" basis. However, I do not know of a site which shows a list of people with such offers. Some of the coaches on the lichess and chess.com lists say they offer first lessons for free. If they don't say that, you can ask, but it will (probably) have to be on a coach-by-coach basis.